# Cannot resolve createSuccessListner in custom request

Tags: android, post, android-volley

Im using volley library in my project and i need to use post method it turns out i have to use a custom request class so i did but in my activity some methods cannot be resolved like this.createRequestSuccessListener(), this.createRequestErrorListener();
here is my code

```
enter code here
String register_url = "xxxxxxx";
                            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyActivity.this);
                            CustomRequest jsObjRequest = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, register_url, params, this.createRequestSuccessListener(), this.createRequestErrorListener());

                            requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

how can this be resolved any help would be appreciated .